# how to get pictures url from instagram API Json result

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

I´m currently trying to get all the URLs for my pictures from my instagram feed and print them out in a simple HTML gallery.

I have managed with "some help" to authenticate and get an `accesstoken` which allows me to get a JSON result containing all my pictures, but I´m totally new to how to fetch all the pictures with the help of JSON.

The code I've got so far looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
//require_once 'src/config.php';

$n_client_id = '87fdd319f8244a728a86f3692527fb15';
$n_client_secret = '040d431d4e0247a292612229446b5240';
$n_redurect_uri = 'http://ideweb2.hh.se/~lukpal12/Startsida.php';

//require_once 'src/Instagram.php';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
$access_token_parameters = array(
    'client_id'     =>     $n_client_id,
    'client_secret'     =>     $n_client_secret,
    'grant_type'        =>     'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'      =>     $n_redurect_uri,
    'code'          =>     $_GET["code"]
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$authObj = json_decode($result);

print_r($result);

$instagram = <<<END
<a href="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2912979/media/recent/?access_token={$authObj->access_token}">Get pictars!</a>
END;

echo $instagram;

echo $authObj->access_token;

?>
```

Since I'm completely new to JSON and how to work with it, I have no idea how the code should be written to do what I'm asking.

After some searching around and after a video or two explaining JSON I managed to get this code to do the `Json_decode`:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2912979/media/recent/?access_token=2912979.87fdd31.0949d22f4a714349ae84643c5af165ef");
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->standard_resolution[0]->url;
```

But that does not work at all. I've got the link to the JSON containing all the data here:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2912979/media/recent/?access_token=2912979.87fdd31.0949d22f4a714349ae84643c5af165ef

If someone would be kind enough to help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First loop will give an array of images with all resolutions, while the second one an array with only standard_resolutions, use print_r to inspect the arrays.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2912979/media/recent/?access_token=2912979.87fdd31.0949d22f4a714349ae84643c5af165ef");
$data = json_decode($json);

// to get the array with all resolutions
$images = array();
foreach( $data->data as $user_data ) {
    $images[] = (array) $user_data->images;
}
// print_r( $images );

// to get the array with standard resolutions
$standard = array_map( function( $item ) {
    return $item['standard_resolution']->url;
}, $images );

// print_r( $standard );
```

**EDIT**

To put these images to a gallery use foreach loop. See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on how to use an array.

```
foreach( $standard as $url ) {
    echo "<img src=\"$url\">";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem, I've got one more question. Now it prints out the image URLs as for example [0] => http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/10254169_321592081322090_1472436591_n.jpg if I want to add all these images to a gallery, how would I separate them and get them all listed in a gallery? sudocode <img src="<?php $standard [0]">

Comment: The answer is updated to show you how to use that array.

Comment: one more: I have to manually put in my user ID but i can retrieve the accesstoken just by adding {$authObj->access_token} after accesstoken= . I tried to do the same för id by typing like this {$authObj->id} since I figured that $authObj contains userID aswell as it is formatted the same way as Accesstoken when I echo out the result. But when I put in {$authObj->id} in the URL like this: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$authObj->id}/media/recent/?access_token={$authObj->access_token} it is returned: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users//media/recent/?access_token={$authObj->access_token}